# Why is a custom collector processing very slow at large number of entries?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I've got a university assignment, but my solution's performance is not good enough so I would like to know how to improve it. I would like to say in advance that I am very new in functional Java programming/streams and my solution is quite basic IMHO.

The dataset: I have a large amount of entries around 350k+. Each entry contains a `data` column which is a byte array and stores some dummy string data, a `timestamp` which indicates the date of addition and the `id` of the entry. The entries are queried with Spring Data JPA Stream.

The entry's model:

```java
public class Entry {
   private long id;
   private long timeStamp;
   private byte[] data;
}
```

The problem: The `data` column of each entry has to be summed up to a given `data size limit`, when the limit is reached I have to make a chunk out of the collected data. A chunk must contain: the collected data, the ID of all processed entries, the earliest and latest entry's timestamp which is present in a chunk.

An example: Lets say we have a data size limit `20kb`. The database contains 350k entries, and if we summarize the `data` of all entries we get `100kb`. So in this case we have to make 5 chunks of 20kb. Each chunk should contain 20kb data, the processed entries and the the earliest and latest timestamp of entries in the chunk.

My solution: The accumulator is a list with 1 element which is a quartet of: earliest timestamp, latest timestamp, the collected data, and the processed entries ids. When the accumulated data size has reached the specified limit we call a `process` method to process that one chunk and we reinitialize the accumulator for the new chunk processing. If it is not reached we just write the current entry's data into the stored data ByteArrayOutputStream and we continue with processing of entries.

The last chunk of data will be processed after the collect function individually.

```java
private Collector<Entry,  List<Quartet<Date, Date, ByteArrayOutputStream, List<Long>>>,  List<Quartet<Date, Date, ByteArrayOutputStream, List<Long>>>> myCustomCollector (int limit) {
    return Collector.of(
            ArrayList::new,
            (accumulatorList, entry) -> {
                if(accumulatorList.isEmpty()) {
                    accumulatorList.add(Quartet.with(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()), new Date(entry.getTimestamp()), new ByteArrayOutputStream(limit), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getId()))));
                } else {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream storedData=accumulatorList.get(0).getValue2();

                    if(storedData.size() + entry.getData().length < limit) {
                        try {
                            storedData.write(entry.getData());

                            Date earliest=accumulatorList.get(0).getValue0();
                            Date latest=accumulatorList.get(0).getValue1();
                            List<Long> containedIds= new ArrayList<>(accumulatorList.get(0).getValue3());

                            earliest = entry.getTimestamp() < earliest.getTime() ? new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) : earliest;
                            latest = entry.getTimestamp() > latest.getTime() ? new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) : latest;
                            containedIds.add(entry.getId());
                            accumulatorList.set(0,Quartet.with(earliest,latest,storedData,containedIds));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // process the elements in the chunk
                        process(accumulatorList.get(0));
                        accumulatorList.set(0, Quartet.with(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()), new Date(entry.getTimestamp()), new ByteArrayOutputStream(limit), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getId()))));
                    }
                }
            },
            (finalList,accList) -> {
                finalList.addAll(accList);
                return finalList;
            }
    );
}
```

The question: This solution works fast for small number of entries, but with large numbers as 350k+ it runs around 5-6 minutes. So my question is why is that and how can I improve the performance? Additionally, can I achieve the same result with the stream processing functions, and how? It would have a better performance than a custom collector? (I felt that my task is quite complex with a lot of summarizing/comparing for using lambdas)

Comment: What do you mean by _summarizing_ the `data` column?

Comment: Summarizing the data means that each entry's `data` is written to a ByteArrayOutputStream until the limit is reached. To be more precise                     `storedData.write(entry.getData());` this line does this job. So for example we have entry1 with a byte array [1,2,3] and entry2 with byte array [3,4,5] then it will be sumamrzied in storedData as [1,2,3,4,5]. And when this storedData has reached the limit it will become a quartet (chunk) which contains the summarized data/timestamps/ids and it will be processed.

Comment: I don’t think this implementation should be slow, but collectors are not really designed for that use case: a collector should be used to aggregate the data, not to send it to some external sink (hence also this weird usage of a list of only 1 element that gets replace after each processing). Note that if you have 350k entries, and each entry only has 1 byte, 20kb chunks will already give you 18 chunks. If entries are bigger (e.g. 1kb) that could create a lot of chunks already. Also, are you sure it isn’t the `process()` method that is slow? Try replacing it with a no-op maybe.

Comment: `new Date(entry.getTimestamp())` appears *six times* in the code. This is already bad quality from source code perspective, but also a waste of resources. Why not keep the `long` returned by `entry.getTimestamp()` and only use that `long`? Likewise, `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getId()))` (learn about `Collections.singletonList(…)`) But also this dealing with `ByteArrayOutputStream` implies lots of unnecessary data copying.

Comment: @Didler 100% that not the process method is the time consumer, I thought about the same at first so I replaced the method call with a log.info, but same results. I agree with you I think it's the collector fault, but I am still not sure what I should replace it with.

A good article about this: https://www.daniellas.tech/posts/speed-of-stream.html

Comment: @Holger I agree there are redundant things which could be done better as you mentioned, I will correct them. However I do not think that these solutions justify this excessive processing time. But thank you for your observations